# VMWare Workstation - Setting up Virtual Network using Windows 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-workstation, virtualization

I would like to set up a virtual network that will consist of 2 VMs with Windows 2008 R2 installed. VM1 would contain active directory/domain controller and VM2 needs to be on the domain controller in VM1. I am not having any luck adding VM2 to the DC. What are steps/configuration I need to follow so that VM1 and VM2 can talk to each other?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start by making sure they're both members of the same virtual network. I suspect your vmware networking settings are explicitly arranged to prevent them from communicating to each other.

Comment: Thanks but how do I go about doing that? I am very new to administration stuff. Is there an article you can direct me to...

Comment: Well, I haven't used VMware Workstation in.... like 5 years.. But in VMware there are settings for your VMs - you can add things like virtual hard drives - in that location, should also be some virtual network cards, which have settings. Anyway, my current VMware knowledge is more industrial strength, so I can't easily explain where to go - but I think looking through that stuff should put ya on the right track. Good luck friend.